# Arrangements of 15 married couples in three rows

Tags: combinatorics

15 married couples are to be seated in 3 rows with 10 seats in each row. Find the number of ways of seating them when the partners of each couple sit next to each other and, in addition, no person sit next to another person of the same gender.

Can someone help me out here?
Not sure what to do after I permute the 15 couples (15!) 
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Are all marriages heterosexual and monogamous?

Comment: @fuglede good question:)

Answer (score 2):

As @fuglede suggested in the comment, Let's suppose all marriages are heterosexual and monogamous.

Firstly, you need to attribute 5 couples for each row, you have ${15\choose 5}{10 \choose 5}$ ways of doing that.

Then for each row, the ways of arranging 5 couples is $5! \times2$, because you can begin with a male or begin with a female.

So finally, you have ${15\choose 5}{10 \choose 5} \times (5! \times2)^3$ ways

Comment: Good explanation. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Since all maried couples in one row must be seated in the same order (husbands on the right of the wives or on the left), all you need is to:

- choose a permutation of those $15$ couples ($15!$), and
- for each row, select the husband/wife order ($2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$)

This yields $15! * 8$ ways in total.